# UIView center property is giving unexpected result

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uikit

I am trying to design the screen programmatically. First, I setup the navigation bar. After that I add a table view and after that I add a plain `UIView`. I am having trouble while using the `.center` property of this last added `UIView`. I want to add a `UIActivityIndicatorView` to this view. My code is as follows (using default height and width of large white activity indicator, which is 37pt each):

```
func setupActivityView() {
    let screen = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, self.navbar.frame.height, screen.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height-self.navbar.frame.height))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.80)
    //view.hidden = true
    self.activityView = view
    self.view.addSubview(view)

    let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .WhiteLarge)
    spinner.startAnimating()
    spinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
    self.spinner = spinner
    /*POINT:1*/ //spinner.center = view.center
    /*POINT:2*/ //spinner.frame.size = CGSizeMake(37.0, 37.0)
    /*POINT:3*/ spinner.frame = CGRectMake((view.frame.width/2) - 18.5, (view.frame.height/2) - 18.5, 37.0, 37.0)
    view.addSubview(spinner)
}
```

In the above code, if you see carefully, I have commented `POINT:1` `POINT:2` and using `POINT:3`. This gives me following result (which is correct and as expected):

[image]

Now, when I use `POINT:1` `POINT:2` and comment `POINT-3` as following:

```
func setupActivityView() {
    let screen = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, self.navbar.frame.height, screen.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height-self.navbar.frame.height))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.80)
    //view.hidden = true
    self.activityView = view
    self.view.addSubview(view)

    let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .WhiteLarge)
    spinner.startAnimating()
    spinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
    self.spinner = spinner
    /*POINT:1*/ spinner.center = view.center
    /*POINT:2*/ spinner.frame.size = CGSizeMake(37.0, 37.0)
    /*POINT:3*/ //spinner.frame = CGRectMake((view.frame.width/2) - 18.5, (view.frame.height/2) - 18.5, 37.0, 37.0)
    view.addSubview(spinner)
}
```

I get following result (which is , I guess, wrong and unexpected):

[image]

So exactly what is the difference my two approaches and what is exactly going wrong here? Is my understanding of this two approaches wrong? If yes then what exactly happens here?

Comment: where you are done allocation this inside view did load?

Comment: Yes. I am calling this function inside `viewDidLoad`

Comment: now you can try my answer bro @The Rohan Sanap

Comment: 20 pixel down display the activity indicator ?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. ViewDidload
>
>    In this method view width and height you will not properly.  You can
>      print view width and height then you will know the reason.
> 2. ViewDidAppear
>
>    viewDidAppear is called when the view is actually visible,  so your
>      code have to place here //now check it

Comment: Did tried to call the method in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`. Same results...

Comment: @TheRohanSanap not only single code ,your whole code ?

Comment: and change the uiview name instead of view.

Comment: Tried. Whole code thing too and changing name too...no difference

Comment: ok do one thing print you view width and height bro ,if it is same as your frame then fine else tell me i give solution.

Comment: `view`'s width and height is correct as expected, i.e., `screenWidth` and `screenHeight - nabbarHeight`

Comment: if it is correct then it should have to work @TheRohanSanap

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104703/discussion-between-the-rohan-sanap-and-kishore-kumar).